# do-while loop in pseudo code

Tags: algorithmicx, pseudocode

The algorithmic package lets me make a while loop as

```
\begin{algorithmic}
  \While{$u\neq v$}
    \State Something
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
```

which results in a

```
while(u is not v) do 
  something 
end while
```

How can I make a do-while loop which result in

```
do
  something
while(u is not v)
```

(Sorry for the lack of output. I don't know how to add that to my question. I hope the question and the intention is clear enough) I use document class memoir and packages algpseudocode and algorithm.

Comment: There's a `\Repeat <text> \Until{<condition>}` construct, if that helps. Same meaning as `do...while`, just different words.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Well, strictly speaking, those two constructs do not have the same meaning, since, for the two loops to be equivalent, the condition used after "until" would have to be the negated version of that used after "while".

Comment: Whoops! Good spot `:)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to define the do-while construct yourself; see below.

Note: you tagged your question with `algorithmicx`, not `algorithmic`, so I produced an answer using the `algorithmicx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Do
    \State Something
  \doWhile{$u \neq v$} % <--- use \doWhile for the "while" at the end
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks indentation very badly for me. The "while" is indented (bizarrely, along with its line number), and if the "do while" is included inside a different block, things get far worse (using some sort of absolute instead of relative indent, and messing up all blocks below the "do while"). I can't figure out how to use \algdef in general, are there examples anywhere?

Comment: I found an easier way to do semantically the same thing: \Repeat \Until in the algpseudocodex package https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex?lang=en