# How do I modify algorithmic \while command to type another word

Tags: overleaf, algorithm2e, algorithmic

How can I type another word for the statement `\while` in the pseudo-code? Normally, it writes,

```
While *some termination condition* do
```

and I want to change it to:

```
DONGU: *some termination condition*
```

And here is the **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\centering
\begin{algorithmic}
\caption{some algorithm} \label{alg:myalgo}
\While {a termination condition bla bla}{
    \STATE $do\;something $\;       
    }
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Your MWE does not compile. It is lacking the `documentclass`, but even with `\documentclass{article}` it still produces errors: the `algorithm` environment from `algorithm2e` package does not require an `algorithmic` in it. Check this out for more detail: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms  It also details how to change the while in `algorithmic`

Comment: This answer details how to change the while keywords in `algorithm2e` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212302/90297

Comment: @EladDen I don't know man but it works on my side as it is. And thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix the formats of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.or/pkg/algorithm2e) and those provided by either [the `algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which supplies the `algorithmic` environment) or [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (which also supplies the `algorithmic` environment).

Here is a purely `algorithm2e` implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{First algorithm}
  \While {a termination condition bla bla}{
    do something\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\SetKwFor{While}{DONGU:}{}{}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Second algorithm}
  \While {a termination condition bla bla}{
    do something\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can also just define your own `\DONGU`:

```
\SetKwFor{DONGU}{DONGU:}{}{}
```

Comment: thanks. it worked like charm. However, I just can't remove any of the environments from my code. It produces error either way. And since my real job is to finish my thesis, I am going to leave it as it is. Thank again.